# Prove $f'''(x) \geq 3$ for some $x \in (-2,2)$, if $f$ is cont on $[-2,2]$ and three times differentiable in $(-2,2)$ & $f(2)=-f(-2)=4$ & $f'(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Prove that there exists a $x \in (-2,2)$ such that $f'''(x) \geq 3$, if $f$ is cont on $[-2,2]$ and three times differtiable in $(-2,2)$ with values $f(2)=-f(-2)=4$ & $f'(0)=0$.

How do I handle $f'''(x)$?

Any hints are welcome.

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^3$, the equation is satisfied.  What happens when you do a variation?

Comment: @Paul Yes I had thought about $x^3$ but what if its coefficient is small enough and the rest (for satisfying the restrictions) is compensated by lower powers of $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define 
$$
g(x) = f(x) - \frac 12 x^3  \, .
$$
Then
$$
g(-2) =  g(2) = 0 \,, \\g'(0) = 0 \, , \\ g'''(x) = f'''(x) - 3\, .
$$

It follows from Taylor's theorem applied to $g$ in the interval $[0, 2]$
that there is a $a \in (0, 2)$ such that
$$
g(2) = g(0) + g'(0) \, (2-0) +  \frac{g''(a)}{2!} \, (2-0)^2
$$
and therefore $g''(a) = - \frac 12 g'(0) \,$.

In the same way we get a $b \in (-2, 0)$
such that $g''(b) = - \frac 12 g'(0) \,$.

So we have $g''(a) = g''(b)$ for some value $b < a$.
It follows from the mean value theorem that there is a $c \in (b, a)$ such that $g'''(c) = 0$, and therefore $f'''(c) = 3$.